# What section of the C++ standard requires that set::erase calls destructors promptly

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, language-lawyer, std

What section of the C++11 standard ([here's a copy of a draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) requires associative containers like std::set, std::map, std::unordered_set, and std::unordered_map to immediately call destructors of objects that are erased from them?

To put it another way - are standard-compliant associative containers allowed to delay (not elide!) their calls to the key and/or value destructors of the keys and values they store?

If not, what section in the standard forbids it?

I ask because I am interested in lazy deletions (sometimes called weak deletions) in associative containers. This is a method of "erasing" a key (or key/value pair) from a structure in which the actual data remains in place, but the node containing it is marked as dead. These are sometimes called tombstones. They are used in many theory papers about data structures, and [sometimes used in practice](https://github.com/nbronson/snaptree/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/stanford/ppl/concurrent/SnapTreeMap.java).

A very simple example is deletion in open-addressed hash tables, which is sometimes implemented with tombstones. When the hash table is eventually rebuilt, all the destructors are called and the tombstoned key/value pairs can be actually and finally deleted and deallocated.

Comment: What's the point in delaying the destruction if you are going to destruct anyway? There would be a point if you could recycle the object and replace destruction+construction by an assignment, but that's not legal.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: With an open-addressed hash table, it preserves the "chain" of items that collided with one original hash bucket (which is possible, but non-trivial by other means). Preserving that "chain" is necessary to assure correct operation.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: The implementation I linked is described in http://ppl.stanford.edu/papers/ppopp207-bronson.pdf. Delaying destruction is used there in order to speed up deletion, especially in a concurrent setting.

Comment: Interestingly, in the table 100 (sequence requirements) in *§ 23.2.3* it is explicitly stated that `clear` *Destroys* all elements while `erase` is only marked as *erasing* them. I wonder if the nuance is intentional and codified. Similarly later on `pop_*` is described as *destroying*.

Comment: Since the answer is apparently not obvious, you should post this question on https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-discussion to get a reliable answer and possibly have the next standard clarified.

Answer (score 1):

There are general requirements in the table for associative containers which describe the requirements for `erase` calls.

E.g. `a.erase(q)` | erases the element pointed to by `q`.

The element type for `map` is a pair of a key and a value. There is no sensible interpretation of "erases" that doesn't involve the proper destruction of the element (key and value). I doubt there is anything more explicitly worded for this situation in the standard.

Comment: I disagree, the element disappearing from any iteration over the container certainly satisfies an interpretation of *erasing* it; and furthermore `clear`, `pop_back` and `pop_front` are explicitly stating as *destroying* elements, so why a different verb for `erase` ?

Comment: I doubt there is anything meant by the distinction. Yes, it does satisfy _an_ interpretation, but in the context of the rest of the standard I would contend that it wasn't a sensible one. (Besides if you could "erase" an object from the container without destroying it at the time of erasure it would no longer be part of that container and wouldn't get _destroyed_ at a later stage. I doubt that that is intented.)

Comment: I don't want to get too deep into what's "sensible", but I tend to agree with some weaker version of what @MatthieuM. says, in that I don't see how "erase" implies "destroy". Perhaps the standard says somewhere something like "When a container erases elements, it must destroy and deallocate them"?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, with regard to your comment, it's not clear to me why "if you could 'erase' an object from the container without destroying it at the time of erasure it would no longer be part of that container and wouldn't get destroyed at a later stage." I think it would not be hard to devise an implementation of a hash table (or even a vector) that could destroy its keys long after it stopped counting them in its size and iterating over them between begin and end.

Comment: @jbapple: I'm not arguing about what _could_ be implemented, I'm just saying that I wouldn't have thought that such an implementation would be a conforming one. My answer is just contending that the reference that I quote is the strongest wording that you are likely to find. If you don't believe that this requires the call of a destructor at the point of erase then this interpretation is really your choice but please do tell the users of your implementation :) .

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I certainly agree that any container which would *not* destroy the element upon erasure would be most surprising. I am just wondering if the wording here slipped (in which case it would be nice to report it and have it reworded) or if there is intentionally some wiggle room left.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, I was trying to say that such an implementation seems like a conformant one.