# Should I assume an object's destructor is called immediately after removal from STL containers?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, destructor

Consider the following code:

```
class T { ... }; // T has a non-trivial destructor

void foo() {
    std::vector<T> v( 5 );
    v.pop_back();

    ...
}
```

After `v.pop_back()`, does the STL guarantee that `T::~T()` has been called for `v.back()`?  Note: The question holds for any method of vector that removes elements (e.g. `resize()`, `erase()`, etc...)

I am writing container classes for my application and I would like them to conform as much as possible to the principles used by the standard library.  If my container class does not make this guarantee, are there any risks?

Comment: Short answer: yeah

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately"? Are you planning to not call the destructor at all, or are you planning to arrange that it will be called later (when someone calls `push_back`, perhaps, or destroys your container)? Either way, your thing won't behave as a container, but it can be closer or further away from what's expected...

Comment: I would be wondering what other operation you have in mind that would cause it

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276180/what-section-of-the-c-standard-requires-that-seterase-calls-destructors-prom/21276830#21276830

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm definitely planning on calling the destructor later (both examples you gave are potential candidates).  Can you elaborate on the potential risks?  E.G., compatibility issues with other parts of the STL or is it simply that callers may be surprised?

Comment: @MarkB: the risk is that since you have no idea what the type `T` is, there might be someone who writes code that relies on its destructor being called at the correct time, or in the correct order, or both. I doubt that anything else in the standard libraries relies on a container destroying correctly though: only the container adaptors can really use your custom container. If you just document that your type is not a Container for certain reason(s) then you're OK in the sense that it's someone else's fault if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector::erase
```

Removes from the vector container and calls destructor on element. The same applies to `std::vector::pop_back`.

```
void pop_back() {
    --this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    this->_M_impl.destroy(this->_M_impl._M_finish);
      }
```

and destroy is a method of allocator:

```
void destroy(pointer __p) { __p->~_Tp(); }
                              ^^^
                            dereference and call destructor
                            on new_allocator::value_type
```

on my implementation allocator for `vector` which is template argument `Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp>` initializes it's base `__glibcxx_base_allocator` whith `new_allocator` due to this definition:

```
 #define __glibcxx_base_allocator  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator 

allocator(const allocator& __a) throw()
      : __glibcxx_base_allocator<_Tp>(__a) { }
```

Comment: This is just one implementation of `vector::pop_back()`

Answer (score 2):

C++11 § 23.2.3 describes the requirements for a sequence container.

The entry for `pop_back()` says it "Destroys the last element."

I suppose you could argue that it doesn't explicitly say immediately. Though, I suspect that was meant to be implied.

Another requirement of note is in § 23.2.1. It says about a container's destructor

> note: the destructor is applied to every element of a; all the memory
>   is deallocated.

So I suppose you could defer destroying the removed elements so long as they're destroyed before the container is destroyed.

That all said if you're truly trying to follow the principles of the standard I can confidently say the standard authors would have expected a removed element to be immediately destroyed.